# how can we invite friends on fanpage to like page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am creating a fanpage and attach in my  facebook apps.
i want to invite my friends form my facebook page to like page and get some offer
so i am using code to display status.

```
 <?php
     require 'facebook.php';
    $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $app_secret,
            'cookie' => true
    )); 

    $user = $facebook->getUser();


    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    $page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
    $page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
    $country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
    $locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

    ?>
```

here using facebook api  to get pageid or user id and other information .

Answer (score 4):

There is no API which allows you to invite a user to like a page, this is only available in Facebook's frontend

Comment: Facebook allows you to import a list of email addresses (from a file or from your email/iCloud, contacts) and then invite. There is no API to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I intend to use (Requests)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You can send their friends a request asking them to like your page ! I guess this is more effective and you decide what should be written in the request!